# Formula parse Error on a date minus one if vlookup has a result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm doing a script which give me a date, this date can be minused if we found a match in a sheet thanks to VLOOKUP formula.

Link of my SpreadSheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GVMULBOIkyFv8EOlxwQ1vLpJcv1U2qqV-WqMCcZg4M0/edit?usp=sharing

```
    var ss = Spreadsheet.getActive();
    var s1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var s2 = ss.getSheets()[1]; // Sheet Name : team
    
      s1.getRange(2,4,5).setFormulaR1C1(=MINUS(INDIRECT(\"RC2\";FALSE);VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(\"RC3\";FALSE);Equipes!A:I;2))"
```

But I've got an error " Error Parse Formula " But if I re-enter the same formula manually; it works.

If someone has a soluce, it would be helpfull !

Ty for reading.

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot mix R1C1 and A1 notation

In addition, you need to put the formula string into quotes and use the correct sheet name.

Rewrite your code as following:

```js
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var s2 = ss.getSheets()[1]; 
  // Sheet Name : Team, not Equipes 
 s1.getRange(2,4,5).setFormulaR1C1('=MINUS(INDIRECT(\"RC2\";FALSE);VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(\"RC3\";FALSE);Team!C[-3]:C[-2];2))');
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about mix R1C1 and A1. Now it works fine ! 

Do you know why these 2 notations can't deal together ?

Comment: I am glad that it works for you!  The reason is that the method `setFormulaR1C1` expects a R1C1 notation.